# Changing Database in run time and making the changes reflect in Django in run time

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

I am developing a Cloud based data analysis tool, and I am using Django(1.10) for that.

I have to add columns to the existing tables, create new tables, change data-type of columns(part of data-cleaning activity) at the run time and can't figure out a way to update/reflect those changes, in run time, in the Django model, because those changes will be required in further analysis process.

I have looked into 'inspectdb' and 'syncdb', but all of these options would require taking the portal offline and then making those changes, which I don't want.

Please can you suggest a solution or a work-around of how to achieve this.

Also, is there a way in which I can select what database I want to work from the list of databases on my MySQL server, after running Django.

Answer (score 0):

Django's ORM might not be the right tool for you if you need to change your schema (or db) online - the schema is defined in python modules and loaded once when Django's web server starts.

You can still use Django's templates, forms and other libraries and write your own custom DB access layer that manipulates a DB dynamically using python.